# What is the correct way to join 3 tables using EF

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

It might be because its a little early in the morning and the brain is not functioning correctly but I have a question regarding the entity framework and SQL

Lets say I have 2 tables

Consumer
ConsumerID
Name
MembershipNumberID

MembershipEntry
MembershipEntryID
EntryDate
MembershipNumberID

A member can have a MembershipNumberID before having a consumerID. Think along the lines of a person collects a membership number and uses the number for the 1st time before associates it with the consumerID.

I some how want to join the tables so I can create a query that returns all of the membership entries even if they don't yet have a consumer assoicated with them.

I have tried to add a FK to the MembershipEntry table however it fails as you would expect due missing id's in the membership table.

Do I just create a 3rd table called MembershipEntries and have 2 FK fields?

I can create a basic join using something like

```
from item in ctx.MembershipEntry
     join c in ctx.Consumer on item.MembershipNumberID  equals c.MembershipNumberID
     select new MembershipViewModel()
     {
     .....................
     }
```

How can I ceate a left outter join using the EF4 to include all entries even if they dont have a membership number yet assoicated with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a third table to join these two tables of data together (that's why it's a relational database!! WOOHOO!). The whole point is to make it "easy" to relate and extract the data. All you need is a simple SQL statement!

Such as this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MembershipEntry 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Consumer on Consumer.MembershipNumberID = MembershipEntry.MembershipNumberID
```

LEFT OUTER JOIN says "Give me everything from MembershipEntry table even if there is nothing to match it in the Consumer table"

See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp for more details and examples!

**NOTE: Some databases may only use LEFT JOIN but SQL uses LEFT OUTER JOIN**

Comment: Thanks DR ideally I am trying to keep it inside the EF4. I thought the left join was the way to go but just not sure how to do it using the EF

Comment: No problemo! Joins used to drive me nuts, but once you get the hang of them, they're quite nice! You can also "fake" join thing buy including two tables in your FROM clause then setting the conditions in your WHERE clause (instead of JOIN ? ON ?)

Answer (score 2):

In LINQ to SQL this would look like this.

```
from item in ctx.MembershipEntry
join c in ctx.Consumer on 
    item.MembershipNumberID equals c.MembershipNumberID into customers
from c in customers.DefaultIfEmtpy()
select new MembershipViewModel()
{
    ...
}
```

I hope it will work for EF too.

Comment: @Diver Dan - You asked how to do left join in LINQ, but marked SQL as an answer?